# Change matrixInput cell color RShiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to change the fill color of some cells in my `matrixInput`.
For example, how can I change the fill color of the second column, say blue (see reproducible example below) ?

I assume that this can be done via CSS, but I'm new to this.

I don't mind using another library or functionality if there's something better, I just need to keep the matrix editable and reactive.

Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

mat <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)

ui <- fluidPage(
    matrixInput(
      "mInput",
      value = mat,
      class = "numeric",
      rows = list(names = F),
      cols = list(names = F)
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Nice minimal example (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS to select the cell at the 2nd row and 3rd column and make it red:

```css
table > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) {background-color: red;}
```

App:

```r
css <- "
table > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) {background-color: red;}
"

library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

mat <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  matrixInput(
    "mInput",
    value = mat,
    class = "numeric",
    rows = list(names = F),
    cols = list(names = F)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```